# React Native Flatlist returns the wrong number of empty rows

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-flatlist

When I run the code below, it displays 3 empty rows. It should be showing two rows each with a color and enddate and I want to use the 'Parent' as the `unique` key. The 'Parent' is the `unique` key created by Firebase when color and enddate were pushed to Firebase with '.push'.

I've tried all sorts of things to get it to display. I did get content to display when I made the 'renderItems' return 'this.state.list', but that returned 3 lines all with the same data, which is the content of the last array on the console log.

I would really appreciate some help to get this working.

Here is the code, a copy of Firebase database and the console.log. Please note that the Firebase 'goal' has been changed to 'color'.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, FlatList, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Button, Card, CardSection } from '../common';
import styles from '../Styles';

class List extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'List',
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      list: [],
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    const Parent = firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/Profile`);

    Parent.on(('child_added'), snapshot => {
        this.setState({ list: [snapshot.key, snapshot.val().color, snapshot.val().enddate] });

    console.log(this.state.list);
    });
}

keyExtractor = (item, index) => index;

render() {
  return (
    <Card>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.list}
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          extraData={this.state}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text style={styles.listStyle}>
                { item.color }
                { item.enddate }
            </Text>
          )}
        />
      </View>

      <CardSection>
        <Button
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'row'
          }}

          onPress={() =>    this.props.navigation.navigate('NextPage', { name: 'user' })}
          title="Go to next page"
        >
          Go to next page
        </Button>
      </CardSection>
    </Card>
    );
  }
}

export { List };
```

[image: Console log entry]
[image: Firebase database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way to store the list

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    const Parent = firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/Profile`);

    Parent.on(('child_added'), snapshot => {
        const newChild = {
           key: snapshot.key, 
           color: snapshot.val().color, 
           enddate: snapshot.val().enddate
        }
        this.setState((prevState) => ({ list: [...prevState.list, newChild] }));

    console.log(this.state.list);
    });
}
```

and your keyExtractor

```
keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.key;
```